# How to re-render path coordinates to reposition svg without a transform:translate

Tags: inkscape

I used InkScape to draw an SVG shaped like a bunny rabbit.  However, I just noticed that the bunny rabbit was sitting out of the page border slightly, so that when I export the SVG, part of the bunny rabbit is clipped.

My initial attempt to fix the problem was to simply drag the bunny rabbit into the center of the InkScape canvas.  But when I did this, I noticed that `transform="translate(26.886705,-44.285911)"` was applied to the `<g>` tag that wraps my `<path>` tag.   This is NOT what I want.  I want InkScape to recalculate my `d="path coordindates"` such that the svg image stays centered in the canvas.

I also tried to use File>Document Properties>Resize Page to Drawing Selection. But this also added a `transform="translate(26.886705,-44.285911)"` .

How do I get InkScape to center my bunny image by recalculating the `d="path coordinates"`?

Comment: see also the `round/rewrite transforms` option of [svgomg](https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/) ([via](https://github.com/sketch-hq/svgo-compressor/issues/20#issuecomment-390392407))

Answer (score 2):

Oh, I figured it out.

First, I delete any transforms from my SVG file by using the XML Editor tool.

[image]

Then I select my SVG on the page and use the Object>Align and Distribute option to align my SVG center along the X and Y axis.

[image]